# How do I retrieve data saved in local storage from a dynamic route with nextjs?

Tags: react-hooks, local-storage, hook, server-side-rendering, next.js13

I am building a nextjs web app that fetches data from an api. Instead of pinging the external api server every time, I've been working on a way to save the json data to localstorage, and to render the data retrieved from localstorage, because the data is relatively static and unchanging.

I've created a useLocalStorage hook that works at "/" route, but not in my nextjs dynamic route. Here is the current code for my hook:

```js
import { useDebugValue } from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function getSavedValue(key, initialValue) {
  const savedValue = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(key));
  if (savedValue) return savedValue;

  if (initialValue instanceof Function) return initialValue();
  return initialValue;
}

export default function useLocalStorage(key, initialValue) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  // first useeffect, handles getting value from storage.
  // second useeffect, handles updating stored value when we change value in our state.
  useEffect(() => {
    const stored = getSavedValue(key, initialValue);
    setValue(stored ? stored : initialValue);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }, [key, value]);

  useDebugValue(value ?? "loading...");

  console.log("value: " + value);

  return [value, setValue];
}
```

The app works as intended in dev when I change the initialValue for the useState in the useLocalStorage hook above to:

```js
const[value,setValue] = useState(getSavedValue(key, initialValue));
```

the app works but throws errors(localstorage not existing on server, only on client) and refuses to build. In order for it to build, i added the useeffects and removed the localstorage stuff out of usestate. this allowed my "/" route to work, but breaks upon navigating to the dynamic details cards route. It seems that I am trying to access properties of the data retrieved from localstorage, but something goes wrong here and an empty array is returned, despite the fact that upon checking localstorage from browser devtools the data has properly been saved in localstorage (through console.logs, it says "countries" is an empty array).

the code below is my "/" route:

```js
"use client";
import useLocalStorage from "@/components/hooks/useLocalStorage";
import useToggle from "@/components/hooks/useToggle";
import CountryCard from "@/components/CountryCard";
import MagnifyingGlass from "@/components/ui/icons/MagnifyingGlass";
import Header from "@/components/Header";

const apiURL = "https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all";

export default function Home() {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useLocalStorage("data", []);
  const [isDarkToggled, setIsDarkToggled] = useToggle("isDark", false);
  const [searchField, setSearchField] = useLocalStorage("search", "");
  const [filterField, setFilterField] = useLocalStorage("filter", "");

  function handleSearch(e) {
    const querySearch = e.target.value;
    setSearchField(querySearch);
  }
  function handleFilter(e) {
    const querySearch = e.target.value;
    setFilterField(querySearch);
  }

  const filteredCountriesRegion = countries.filter((country) =>
    country.region.toLowerCase().includes(filterField.toLowerCase())
  );

  const filteredCountries = filteredCountriesRegion.filter((country) =>
    country.name.common.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase())
  );

  const fetchCountries = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(apiURL);
    const data = await response.json();
    setCountries(data);
    localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(countries));
  };

  return (
    <main className={`${isDarkToggled ? "dark" : ""}`}>
      <Header handleToggle={setIsDarkToggled} />
      <div className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center pt-20 bg-light-gray text-dark-blue-2 dark:bg-dark-blue-1 dark:text-white">
        <div className="flex flex-col justify-between w-full px-4 gap-4">
          <div className="flex flex-row border-transparent rounded-lg p-2 text-dark-gray dark:bg-dark-blue-0">
            <MagnifyingGlass className="p-2 px-6" />
            <input
              id="search"
              name="search"
              className="p-2 outline-none flex-grow bg-transparent"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search for a country..."
              onChange={(e) => handleSearch(e)}
              value={searchField}
            />
          </div>
          <select
            name="filter"
            id="filter"
            className="rounded-lg bg-white w-fit p-4 self-start dark:bg-dark-blue-0"
            onChange={(e) => handleFilter(e)}
          >
            <option className="hidden" value="">
              Filter by Region
            </option>
            <option value="">All</option>
            <option value="Africa">Africa</option>
            <option value="America">America</option>
            <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
            <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
            <option value="Oceania">Oceania</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col w-full p-10 gap-6 md:flex-row md:flex-wrap md:justify-center">
          {filteredCountries &&
            filteredCountries.map((country, index) => (
              <CountryCard key={index} data={country} />
            ))}
        </div>
        <button className="bg-slate-500 text-black" onClick={fetchCountries}>
          fetch countries
        </button>
        {/* <p>api endpoint: {apiURL}</p> */}
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

and the code below is my dynamic route "/country/[countryName]":

```js
"use client";

import React from "react";
import useLocalStorage from "@/components/hooks/useLocalStorage";
import Header from "@/components/Header";
import useToggle from "@/components/hooks/useToggle";
import CountryDetailsCard from "@/components/CountryDetailsCard";
import Link from "next/link";

export default function CountryDetailPage({ params }) {
  // console.log(typeof params.countryName);

  const [countries, setCountries] = useLocalStorage("data", []);
  const [isDarkToggled, setIsDarkToggled] = useToggle("isDark", false);

  const countryNameWithSpaces = params.countryName.replaceAll("-", " ");
  const countryByName = countries.filter(
    (country) =>
      country.name.common.toLowerCase() === countryNameWithSpaces.toLowerCase()
  );
  const country = countryByName[0];
  const countryNativeName = country.name.nativeName
    ? Object.values(country.name.nativeName)
    : null;

  function borderCountry(inputString) {
    const countryByCode = countries.filter(
      (item) => item.cca3.toLowerCase() === inputString.toLowerCase()
    );
    const outputString = countryByCode[0].name.common;
    return outputString;
  }

  const countryBorders = country.borders
    ? country.borders.map((border) => borderCountry(border))
    : [];

  const countryCurrencies = country.currencies
    ? Object.values(country.currencies).map((item) => item.name)
    : null;

  const countryLanguages = country.languages
    ? Object.values(country.languages)
    : null;

  const countryDetails = {
    name: country.name.common,
    nativeName: countryNativeName ? countryNativeName[0].common : null,
    flag: country.flags.svg,
    alt: country.flags.alt,
    population: country.population.toLocaleString("en-US"),
    region: country.region,
    subRegion: country.subregion,
    capital: country.capital,
    topLevelDomain: countryByName[0].tld,
    currencies: countryCurrencies,
    languages: countryLanguages,
    borderCountries: countryBorders,
  };

  return (
    <main className={`${isDarkToggled ? "dark" : ""}`}>
      <Header handleToggle={setIsDarkToggled} />
      <div className="flex flex-col gap-4 px-8 pt-20 pb-4 dark:text-white dark:bg-dark-blue-1 min-h-screen">
        <Link
          className="w-fit p-2 px-4 border-transparent rounded-md dark:bg-dark-blue-0"
          href="/"
        >
          &lt; Back
        </Link>
        <CountryDetailsCard params={params.countryName} {...countryDetails} />
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

when the app breaks it points to this line of code from above saying "country" is undefined:

```js
  const countryNativeName = country.name.nativeName
    ? Object.values(country.name.nativeName)
    : null;
```

I think it has to do with initial renders, and useeffects. Please let me know if more info is needed.

I thought it was my hook that has the issue, so I've been trying different solutions involving some conditionals to see if window is rendered, but they did not fix it. Now I do not think the hook is the problem, but think the code for the dynamic route might be wrong. something is happening where I cannot properly retrieve the data from localstorage.

Could it be an issue of asynchronous functions or something? Trying to apply an algorithm on an undefined/empty array/object.

Answer (score 0):

This is embarassing, it turns out that my error was due to the data processing within the dynamic route page. I just needed some conditional logic so that if the data was not properly set, it would still have something for rendering. I still don't understand the nuances behind this solution, but if I had to take a crack at it, I would say that it would break on initial render because some data was set yet with my local storage hook, and once properly set with useEffect, it rerenders with the appropriate data.

For countryNativeName and other variables, make sure the turnary conditionals do not have any methods or accessed any properties.

```js
const countryNativeName = country ? Object.values(country.name.nativeName) : null;
```

and

```js
const countryDetails = {
  name: country ? country.name.common : null
}
```

Hope this is helpful to someone.